# Programmatically Create a Full Text Population Schedule via TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SQL 2005 TSQL script which sets up my FT Catalog and Indexes, but I would like to also create a Population schedule for these indexes via the same Code, can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: The best advice I could find regarding this question was to turn on SQL profiler and look at its output when using the SQL GUI to create a schedule.  The resulting TSQL is very laborious, so I gave up on this and continue to do it the manual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Comment below question.